# Dados repetidos com GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sql, group-concat

Estou com um problema quando eu faço um `SELECT` no meu BD, estou usando `GROUP_CONCAT` para concatenar a coluna de telefones e email mas estou pegando dados repetidos.

Aqui está o `SELECT`:

```
SELECT contatos.cont_id
     , contatos.cont_firstname
     , contatos.cont_lastname
     , contatos.data_nasc
     , contatos.anotacoes
     , GROUP_CONCAT(contatos_email.email)
     , contatos_telefone.telefone
     , contato_endereco.rua
     , contato_endereco.numero
     , contato_endereco.bairro
     , contato_endereco.cidade
     , contato_endereco.estado
     , contato_endereco.pais 
FROM contatos 
JOIN contatos_email ON contatos.cont_id = contatos_email.contato_id 
JOIN contatos_telefone ON contatos.cont_id = contatos_email.contato_id
JOIN contato_endereco ON contatos.cont_id = contato_endereco.contato_id
```

na coluna em que esta sendo exibido os emails era para aparecer apenas 3 emails e não ficar repetindo como esta agora...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, adicione um exemplo de como os dados estão sendo retornados atualmente e como você deseja que seja o resultado final.Facilitará o entendimento de sua questão.

Comment: Você está usando `GROUP_CONCAT` sem fazer `GROUP` ou qualquer função de agregação. O que pretende que aconteça?

Comment: pronto editei a pergunta... Agora acho que da pra entender melhor :)

Comment: Tentou `GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT contatos_email.email )`? Qual é o servidor de DB que está usando?

Comment: estou usando o maria db no phpmyadmin

Comment: @Bacco deu certo fiz como você disse coloquei o GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT contatos_email.email) e funcionou Vlw :)

Comment: Bom que resolveu. Como vc já postou a solução, marque como resolvida no V verdinho do lado da sua resposta, para a postagem ficar completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi essa

```
SELECT contatos.cont_id, 
contatos.cont_firstname,
contatos.cont_lastname, 
contatos.data_nasc, 
contatos.anotacoes,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct contatos_email.email),
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT contatos_telefone.telefone), 
contato_endereco.rua, contato_endereco.numero, 
contato_endereco.bairro, contato_endereco.cidade, 
contato_endereco.estado, contato_endereco.pais 
FROM contatos 
LEFT JOIN contatos_email ON contatos.cont_id = contatos_email.contato_id 
LEFT JOIN contatos_telefone ON contatos.cont_id =  contatos_email.contato_id
LEFT JOIN contato_endereco ON contatos.cont_id = contato_endereco.contato_id 
group by contatos.cont_id
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]